# Can I add passengers later for free to my booking for the DFDS Dover-Calais / Dunkirk ferry?

Tags: bookings, ferries

I am planning to travel from the UK to France via one of the DFDS ferries. Currently we only know that there will be two of us, but there is a chance that a third and a fourth person might accompany us as well. As this is a car ferry the amount of passengers doesn't increase the cost of booking, but I have to name everyone during booking (this is in contrast to the Eurotunnel, where they don't care about the names of the passengers at booking time).

Their [FAQ site](http://www.dfdsseaways.co.uk/Customer-Service/dover-dunkirk/FAQs/#FAQ24) only states what I should do in case there is a different number of passengers for the return trip. Is it possible to add new passengers to my booking for free at a later date after booking? It seems like I could just add everyone's names to the booking and cross them out later, but that seems like an overkill.

Comment: Any reason why you can't add all 4 passengers and leave them in the booking, regardless of whether or not they make it?

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't know exactly at the moment who might join us. Of course I have a pool of people, but adding all of them seems like I just want to game the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When reading the FAQ and different parts of the website, the provided information is quite confusing, it might be possible to add passengers for free, depending on your fare type.

- For one, [they mention](http://www.dfdsseaways.co.uk/Customer-Service/dover-dunkirk/FAQs/#FAQ2) that any change for the Dover-Dunkirk route should happen on the phone and that there will be a cost of 10GBP/15EUR plus the difference between the former and new price (depending on the day you change your booking)
- But at the top of the website, there is an ["Amend"](http://www.dfdsseaways.co.uk/myprofile/login/) link and the details of possible operations include `Amend passenger details, date/time of travel, vehicle type` for routes from Dover to France. There is a [help section](http://www.dfdsseaways.co.uk/customer-service/my-bookings-guide/amending-a-booking-online/) about this amendment feature and it says `simply go through the same booking process that you did when originally making`, which suggests you can change the information you filled in the first place. It mentions that before the booking is actually updated, you would have to pay the possible extra charges.

On top of that, they [offer two fare types](https://www.dfdsseaways.co.uk/Customer-Service/cross-channel/fare-types/), and clearly state the Economy type has a 10GBP charge for booking amendments, but not the Flexi type. So most likely, any change would result in a 10GBP charge.

If you already made a booking, I would recommend you to try the amendment tool right away and try to simulate your changes, to see if you can actually amend your booking and if they charge you any extra.

If you have not made a booking yet, try to ask your friends to make a decision before you book, since the amendment is likely not to be free if you book the "Economy" fare. Note that if you book at least 2 days in advance (e.g. a Wednesday for the Friday), prices do not fluctuate a lot. They seem to change from 35 to 65 GBP, probably depending more on the time of the week/time of the year than how early you book. In particular the 10 GBP charge seems to matter more than or at least as much as the price fluctuation (I have not run a deep analysis of the price evolution but prices 2 days away can be as low as 35 GBP, except on Friday evening, and prices a month away can be as high as 65 GBP)

Comment: My friend often travels Dover Dunkirk, and has added extra passengers, online, to the booking, without costs. Booking as early as certain of traveling and later having an 'add people' request.

Comment: @Willeke you can probably add that as an answer, if that is always the case that's worth knowing

Answer (score 4):

Concerning myself, it is free (no added cost) to add a passenger (less than 27hrs before departure exactly when I did it). Make sure your bookings details are right. Data treatment can be surprising sometimes.

Also heard 2 years ago that you can add someone directly at the control desk of the ferry company but I can not remember which one it was.